# Content Box Pushing Footer Down and Creating White Space on Background Image (CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I have a content box on my website that pushes whitespace beneath the background image, pushing the footer down far. How do I design my CSS so my content box remains a max-height but can still have a lot of content? I have tried a few things but it has made a very ugly second scrollbar that really looks amateur.

I also want the footer to stick to the bottom of the page. Hope this isn't asking too much in one question.

Added link to jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/theflyingmouse/XU455/

```
.hentry {

word-wrap: break-word;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.site-footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 72px;
}

body.custom-background {
background-size: cover;
}

.site-main {
    padding-top: 10px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
background-color: rgba(33, 43, 40, 0.42);
width: 70%;
opacity: 0.95;
height: auto; 
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: learn how to use a browser console to live edit css , turn rules off and on by clicking on then etc for your troubleshooting needs...you'll be surprised how quickly you can find problems and solutions

Comment: I've tried a few things. Various overflow options, height adjustments. Just stumped and need a little help.

Comment: Let me try to clarify, max height of your content area is the height of your background image? And you want to maintain the same amount of content all other factors equal?

Comment: to be honest I'm not clear on what issue is. When I look at background image by itself I see it ends at bottom in boys gut area....see same on page before whitespace

Comment: footer stick to bottom is simple with `position:fixed`

Comment: The max height of the content box should just be a little above the bottom edge of the background. Check it out live to see the issue.

[link](www.chrispicco.ca/about)